# Why is there information available while browsing that is not available using the graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

There is profile information, like interests, education and work history, that is available to me when I am browsing profiles of users who are not my friends (while logged in and while logged out).
However this information is not available using the graph api, using an access token given by my user with the maximum permissions possible.

Why is that? Am I doing something wrong or is that the policy of Facebook to expose more information while browsing the site than while using the graph api?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is how things works when using the API, you could confirm this easily by hitting the Graph of any user (without even connecting to Facebook):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/zuck
```

Result:

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

Now with a user `access_token` I got a couple more fields:

```
{
  "id": "4",
  "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
  "first_name": "Mark",
  "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/zuck",
  "username": "zuck",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "updated_time": "2011-10-02T21:26:46+0000",
  "type": "user"
}
```

So back to your question:

> **Does Facebook expose more information about *public profiles* while browsing the site than
>   while using the graph api?**

**YES**